# Finding Current Location in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to find current location, and this is my code.

```
 LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);        
        Location location =new Location(mlocManager.GPS_PROVIDER);      

 System.out.println("***longitude **"+location.getLongitude());
        System.out.println("***latitude **"+location.getLatitude());
```

but when i run app it always display 0.0 
can anyone see the problem?

Comment: try using NETWORK_PROVIDER, if you checking it indoor.

Comment: no i don't get any error

Comment: @YouddhDid it solved your issue?

Comment: yes it's done,problem is only emulator when i try it in device it's working fine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Location location =new Location(mlocManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

after writing this statement if you put your cursor over Location You will come to know extact meaning of this statement.

As per Google Doc

> above Constructs a new Location. By default, time, latitude,
>   longitude, and numSatellites are 0; hasAltitude, hasSpeed, and
>   hasBearing are false; and there is no extra information.

You need to fire `requestLocationUpdate` to get Lat & lon(If any).

Also since you are running this example on Emulator.You will need to emulate send Lat & Lon
manually.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Location is acquired asynchronously. You need to register a `LocationListener` with your `LocationManager`, whose `onLocationChanged(Location l)` will be called whenever a new location information is available.

Comment: yes this is one solution , but this method is not working for emulator because emulator cant change location so is their any other option for me...

Comment: You should use mock locations. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#MockData

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the app in the real device not in the emulator. Also your device should be data enabled.

Also give uses:permission in the `Menifest` file. `FINE_LOCATION`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you meant to do was this

```
Location location = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

But please note that this will only work if your gps has already grabbed a previous location. So on the emulator you will need to send a location BEFORE this line is called, and on a real device the gps will have to have been activated before the line and have received a location.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
package com.ShowLocationActivity;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Locale;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.location.Address;
 import android.location.Criteria;
 import android.location.Geocoder;
 import android.location.Location;
 import android.location.LocationListener;
 import android.location.LocationManager;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;


  public class ShowLocationActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
private TextView latituteField;
private TextView longitudeField;
private TextView placeName;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
    placeName=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView06); 
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {
    //  Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf("Provider " + provider + " has been selected."), 600).show();
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
    } else {
        latituteField.setText("Provider not available");
        longitudeField.setText("Provider not available");
    }

    try {
        Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
        if (addresses.isEmpty()) {
            placeName.setText("Waiting for Location");
        }
        else {
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                placeName.setText(addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getLocality() +", " + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Location Name Found", 600).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

    try {
        Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
        if (addresses.isEmpty()) {
            placeName.setText("Waiting for Location");
        }
        else {
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                placeName.setText(addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getLocality() +", " + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Location Name Found", 600).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Here is the Xml File

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:text="Latitude: "
        android:textSize="20dip" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="unknown"
        android:textSize="20dip" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:text="Longitute: "
        android:textSize="20dip" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="unknown"
        android:textSize="20dip" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView05"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:text="Place Name "
        android:textSize="20dip" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView06"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="unknown"
        android:textSize="20dip" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.ShowLocationActivity"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission> 
   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".ShowLocationActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Works for me.. try this, it will work for u 2.... :)