# Location returns always null - android

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, android-mapview, android-location

**Location returns always null from this code. Please check my codes and tell me whats wrong. When I run the project on debug mode, provider="network" but location always null. I send latitude and longitude values by using DDMS but doesn't change. I don't understand whats is the problem**

**This part in the onCreate method**

```
lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

        provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            updateLocation(location);
```

**This part in the onResume method**

```
@Override   
    protected void onResume() {  
        super.onResume();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000, 10, this);
    }
```

**I use LocationListener (MapActivity implements LocationListener) and this is onLocationChanged part**

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        updateLocation(location);   
    }
```

**finally this is my updateLocation()**

```
private void updateLocation(Location location){
        if (location != null) {
            Double lat = location.getLatitude()*1E6;
            Double lng = location.getLongitude()*1E6;
            point = new GeoPoint(lat.intValue(), lng.intValue());

            mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
            mc = mapView.getController();
            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            //List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            myLocOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
            //overlays.add(myLocOverlay);
            mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocOverlay);
            myLocOverlay.enableMyLocation();

            myLocOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mc.animateTo(myLocOverlay.getMyLocation());
                    }
            }); 

            mc.setZoom(15);
            mapView.invalidate();

            }

    }
```

**I gave essential permissions and I use google maps library**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />

<uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" >
        </uses-library>
```

Comment: are you using this code on an emulator?

Comment: Yes. Also I install to phone but it doesn't work.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183859/finding-current-location-in-android

Comment: Try to get location by another method getProvider("GPS");

Comment: My code going crazy :D I uninstall app on my device and reinstall it, then it works. But on the emulator, it doesnt work although I send latitude and longitude by using DDMS. 

I install on HTC Wildfire and app is working but I install on HTC One X and app doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u should use LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER to request. You can test my code:

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1l,1f, new LocationListener() {        
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        updateLocation(location);               
    }
    });
```

Good luck!
^-^

Comment: Your code works like my code. On HTC Wildfire works great but On emulator and on HTC One X it doesnt work.